# Using ADO datatable copy() to restore original table data

Tags: ado.net, datatable

I have the datatable bound to a datagrid where the user can see the changes he/she's making.  I make a copy of the table before changes start so that I can put the original data back if the user decides not to accept the changes.

Making the copy uses very simple syntax (VB):

```
Dim copyDataTable As DataTable
copyDataTable = dataset.table.Copy()
```

However, reversing the syntax to:

```
dataset.table = copyDataTable
```

Gives "dataset.table is read only."

The only example I can find for using datatable Copy() is to create a *new* table, not copy back to an existing one.

I suspect there is some simple syntax or method, equivalent to making the copy, but so far no luck in finding it.

Anyone familiar with how to do it, or even a different approach to what I'm trying to do?

Thanks,
Chas

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a different and much simpler approach answered on MSDN:

Actually, if the user doesn't want to save the changes, all you need to do is dataset.RejectChanges(), which will put your DataSet back to it's original state (assuming you haven't issued an .AcceptChanges() at any point).

~~Bonnie Berent DeWitt [C# MVP]